# Move image left or right in a UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview

Hey guys I'm wondering how would you be able to move an image an imageView. I'm using an imageView in my storyboard that looks something like this.

[image]

This is how the original image looks like.

[image]

This is how I would like image view to look like

[image]

Make the image move to the left or align it to the right but at the same time keep it aspect fill. This is what happens when the content mode is right. The image is way to big and looks like this.

[image]

My imageView content mode is aspect fill. I would like to move the image in the imageView a little to the left. Would I need a scrollview in order to do this? Would appreciate any help or links. Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need to add a scrollView. Have you tried adding some leading a trailing constraints?

Comment: set content mode to aspect fit or another option is to adjust the image view constraints so that image view resize accordingly with respect to image width and height.

Comment: Do you *want* the image to be scrollable? Or do you just want it set to Aspect Fill but Aligned Right?

Comment: Thanks guys for responding to my question. I've edited the question. Please check it out. Thanks

Comment: Looks like this may be of interest: https://github.com/reydanro/UIImageViewAligned  ... should do what you want and more.